# Team availability - Interaction challenge

Tags: interaction-design, microinteractions, information-design

I have an interesting interaction problem to solve. I'm working on an app which has a functionality called team availability. The challenge is that the user needs to see the teams availability for the next 4 events.

The team may be made out of 200 people, but the people who are gonna play for that event might be 4 and they might differ from one event to the other. I've attached below what I got until now.

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this? [image: screenshot]

Comment: Not sure if it helps you, but a dutch website https://datumprikker.nl/?hl=en tries to solve a similar problem, picking a date with a group of people, based on their availability. Maybe it helps you in visualizing availability & the interaction of availability input.

Comment: https://cally.com/ - this is the international website btw. Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't wanna influence, but maybe it would be an idea to group them

see attachement

[image]

Comment: Hi there, the copy you provided makes this potentially good answer into a low quality one. Avoid personal qualifying statements like "I don't want to influence but maybe..." or "you have to have listen to me but...", or "it's just my opinion but...". If we remove this from your answer and edit it down, we get "Group them". A good answer should provide some rationale the approach given.

Comment: needs some colour coding to reinforce yes/no availability